# What are Windows 8 "spellchecking preferences"?

Tags: windows-8, spell-check

I added another language to my Windows 8 machine.  In the language options, there is a set of radio buttons titled "Spellchecking Preferences" with the following options:

- Full
- Partial
- Mixed
- Mixed Authoritative

My US-English default language does not have this option.  I cannot find what the choices here mean in any documentation.  What do these options do and why do they only show up for some languages?

Comment: it would be great if you tell us what language you added im willing to bet that they are language specific options

Comment: I saw it with more than one language, but I'm primarily interested in Hebrew.

Comment: @MosheKatz although this question is several years old, I thought you might like to know that I authored an answer within [this new question](https://superuser.com/q/1341924/650163).  Hopefully the information is still beneficial.