# Language Options -> Spell Checking in Windows 10 version 1803

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1803

What's the difference between the Spell check settings in the Language Options of Windows 10 version 1803?  The options I see are as follows:

- Full
- Partial
- Mixed
- Mixed Authorized

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon your screenshot, you have a language pack installed and this appears to be the various options associated with **Hebrew mode**:

> Specifies the script to use for checking spelling of Hebrew text.

The description of each option looks like this:

> **xlHebrewFullScript** (default) The conventional script type as required
>   by the Hebrew Language Academy when writing non-diacritisized text.
>
> **xlHebrewMixedAuthorizedScript** The Hebrew traditional script.
>
> **xlHebrewMixedScript** In this mode the speller accepts any word
>   recognized as Hebrew, whether in Full Script, Partial Script, or any
>   non-conventional spelling variation that is known to the speller.
>
> **xlHebrewPartialScript** In this mode the speller accepts words both in
>   Full Script and Partial Script. Some words will be flagged since this
>   spelling is not authorized in either Full script or Partial script.
>
> A legitimate Hebrew word can be a basic dictionary entry or any inflection.

---

Sources:
[Administrative Templates (Users) - Hebrew mode](https://getadmx.com/?Category=Office2013&Policy=office15.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_Hebrewmode)
[Microsoft Excel Visual Basic - HebrewModes Property](https://documentation.help/Microsoft-Excel-Visual-Basic/xlproHebrewModes.htm)
[Excel VBA - SpellingOptions.HebrewModes Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/spellingoptions-hebrewmodes-property-excel)

Comment: It sounds to me like "Mixed" (xlHebrewMixedScript) is the most permissive option, which will accept the widest variety of possible Hebrew spelling variations.  I wonder if it might even accept some informal spelling variations, which are technically incorrect, but commonly used anyway.